# Storing SESSION data all within a single form

Tags: php, session

I am trying to store data in `$_SESSION` variables so I can use it in other parts of the form.

I have an input for team name which I need to use within a drop down a couple of steps down the form, the team name come from the user input only.

Im struggling to pass this data throughout the form and then post it at the end.

The session is being set in `header.php`

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['dashboardName'] = $_POST['dashboardName'];
    $_SESSION['teamName'] = $_POST['teamName'];
    $_SESSION['firstName'] = $_POST['firstName']; 
    $_SESSION['lastName'] = $_POST['lastName'];      
    $_SESSION['memberTeam'] = $_POST['memberTeam']; 
    $_SESSION['stenData'] = $_POST['stenData'];
    $_SESSION['score_1'] = $_POST['score_1'];
    $_SESSION['score_2'] = $_POST['score_2']; 
    $_SESSION['score_3'] = $_POST['score_3']; 
    $_SESSION['score_4'] = $_POST['score_4'];  
    $_SESSION['score_5'] = $_POST['score_5']; 
    $_SESSION['score_6'] = $_POST['score_6']; 
    $_SESSION['score_7'] = $_POST['score_7']; 
    $_SESSION['score_8'] = $_POST['score_8'];                                           
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">

<!-- STEP :: 1 -->
    <div class="step-one">
    <h1>STEP 1</h1>
        <input type="text" name="dashboardName" required placeholder="Dashboard Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['dashboardName']; ?>">
        <button class="step-one-next">Next</button>
    </div>

<!-- STEP :: 2 -->
    <div class="step-two">
    <h1>STEP 2</h1>
        <input type="text" name="teamName" placeholder="Team name" required value="<?php echo $_SESSION['teamName']; ?>">
        <button class="step-two-previous">Previous</button>   
        <button class="step-two-next">Next</button>        
    </div>

<!-- STEP :: 3 -->
    <div class="step-three">
    <h1>STEP 3</h1>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstName']; ?>">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lastName']; ?>">
        <button class="step-three-previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="step-three-next">Next</button>
    </div>

<!-- STEP :: 4 -->    
    <div class="step-four">
    <h1>STEP 4</h1>
        <select name="memberTeam">
            <option><?php echo $_SESSION['teamName']; ?></option>
        </select>
        <button class="step-four-previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="step-four-next">Next</button>        
    </div>

<!-- STEP :: 5 -->     
    <div class="step-five">
    <h1>STEP 5</h1>
        <textarea name="stenData" placeholder="Paste Sten Data..." required><?php echo $_SESSION['stenData']; ?></textarea>
        <button class="step-five-previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="step-five-next">Next</button>        
    </div>

<!-- STEP :: 6 -->   
    <div class="step-six">  
    <h1>STEP 6</h1>
        <select name="score_1">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_1']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>  

        <select name="score_2">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_2']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>  

        <select name="score_3">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_3']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 

        <select name="score_4">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_4']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 

         <select name="score_5">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_5']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 

        <select name="score_6">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_6']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 

         <select name="score_7">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_7']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 

        <select name="score_8">
            <option selected="selected"><?php echo $_SESSION['score_8']; ?></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select> 
        <button class="step-six-previous">Previous</button>
        <button class="step-six-next">Next</button>                           
    </div>




<!-- STEP :: 7 -->
    <div class="step-seven">   
    <h1>STEP 7</h1> 
    <p><?php echo $_SESSION['dashboardName']; ?></p>
        <button class="step-seven-previous">Previous</button>
        <input type="submit" name="test" value="Submit">
    </div>

</form>

<script>
$(".step-one-next").click(function(){
    $(".step-one").hide();
    $(".step-two").show();
});
$(".step-two-previous").click(function(){
    $(".step-two").hide();
    $(".step-one").show();
});
$(".step-two-next").click(function(){
    $(".step-two").hide();
    $(".step-three").show();
});
$(".step-three-previous").click(function(){
    $(".step-three").hide();
    $(".step-two").show();
});
$(".step-three-next").click(function(){
    $(".step-three").hide();
    $(".step-four").show();
});
$(".step-four-previous").click(function(){
    $(".step-four").hide();
    $(".step-three").show();
});
$(".step-four-next").click(function(){
    $(".step-four").hide();
    $(".step-five").show();
});
$(".step-five-previous").click(function(){
    $(".step-five").hide();
    $(".step-four").show();
});
$(".step-five-next").click(function(){
    $(".step-five").hide();
    $(".step-six").show();
});
$(".step-six-previous").click(function(){
    $(".step-six").hide();
    $(".step-five").show();
});
$(".step-six-next").click(function(){
    $(".step-six").hide();
    $(".step-seven").show();
});
$(".step-seven-previous").click(function(){
    $(".step-seven").hide();
    $(".step-six").show();
});
</script>
```

So the end goal is to input the inputs at each stage, name the team and then the team names be available in the drop down on the `memberTeam` `<select>`

Comment: silly question? did you start the session?

Comment: What's exactly happening here? "Not working" isn't enough information to go off of.

Comment: Yeah there's no question in OP. Please modify question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, the session starts within header.php, I am able to store the inputs into the session variables but for some reason when it comes to the team select it just dosnt show form the input set in `teamName`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I never said anywhere it isnt working?

Comment: @PhpDude You mentioned that *"Im struggling to pass this data throughout the form and then post it at the end."*. But it's still quite broad. We need more information on what's currently happening.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The problem I have is passing session data throughout the form, I understand that with Php there needs to be a refresh to submit but I need to store the teamName (step 2) on user input and then that be available to select on memberTeam (step 4)

Comment: Have a read at the manual with examples http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: If this is to be a value, then try setting it as a value, if that's what the question is about `<option value="<?php echo $_SESSION['teamName']; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['teamName']; ?></option>` and checking if the session is set / not empty `isset()` - `!empty()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have yes, that is exactly where I found the idea to use sessions to store this data

Comment: @Fred-ii- - The question is really: I want the user to type in a team name into the 'teamName' input field and then that become available as an option in the dropdown 'memberTeam' but I can only get it in there by submitting the form, is there a way other than sessions where I can temp store that input value and use it in the drop down?

Comment: that's just it; it needs to be submitted in order for it to take effect. What you need here is ajax, not just jQuery/JS if you don't want to reload the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133040/discussion-between-phpdude-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you hit Next button, the form data don't post to server. You can change to `<button type="submit" class="step-one-next">Next</button>` (add type as submit), but you need to handle which step you're in and which step is next when hit Next. Otherwise, it's easier to use JavaScript.

**Updated using jQuery:**
https://jsfiddle.net/79nj8e7p/1/

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to put as comment.

Comment: Hey, so my steps actually show and hide each div. Ill update the question.

Comment: Can I store inputs with JQuery?

Comment: Yes, you can. Are you using jQuery to show/hide step?

Comment: I am yes! Ill update the question

Comment: Yes, use javascript to store and update the select input is easy and more straightforward way.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do that?

Comment: Of course, I will post in next reply.

Comment: Sounds good man

Comment: Hey man, as committed. Here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/79nj8e7p/1/

Comment: Hey dude, that dosnt seem to work man, its kinda not what I was looking for. So the Issue I have is I want to create the dashboard name, create the teams and then create the user, but have the team names from the previous populated in a select/option dropdown...

Comment: Actually, what you have done I can work with that!